# Count occurrence in a table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

All, I have one table with two columns, there can be any number of rows and the Type and Location names can be anything though the Type is always in alphabetical order -

```
Type    Location

Inmate  Holding
Inmate  Holding
Inmate  Processing
Person  Processing
Person  Reception
Person  Reception
Person  Reception
Visitor Processing
Visitor Reception
Visitor Reception
```

I need to count the occurences of Type relative to Location, so the result would be -

```
Quantity    Type    Location

2   Inmate  Holding
1   Inmate  Processing
1   Person  Processing
3   Person  Reception
1   Visitor Processing
2   Visitor Reception
```

I thought of using select Type(Count* etc but this just adds all the Types and tells me there are 10 (rows) and select distinct Type(Count does not seem to work.

I believe I can do this with variables, detect a change of Type or Location name etc but I prefer not to have to create a stored procedure (in MySQL).

Is there an alternative method?

Regards, Active

Comment: "Type is always in alphabetical order" Data in the relational database are sets, therefore, they are unordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried group by both Columns and in **select** arranging count before the other columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Type, Location from TABLE GROUP BY Type, Location
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select Type, Location , count(*) from table group by Type, Location;
```

Comment: Thank you both Umais and Krishnakumar (working fine). Fortunately this forum includes people who think more logically than me.

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can accept the solution as Answer if it's good for you

Comment: Sadly, how you  accept the solution as Answer if it's good for you is not obvious to me, there appears to be no button / link in order to do so, so I accept your anwers in this comment.

Comment: Ah, found it (large tick).